# sonata_type_collection when submiting empty data should be like not adding tem

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

In the admin of an entity I have something like this:

```
$formMapper->add('answers', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
    'label' => 'Respuestas',
    'by_reference' => false,
    'required' => false
), array(
    'edit' => 'inline',
    'inline' => 'table'
));
```

I want to ask if it is possible to threat empty data as if the row is not added so it will not be inserted? I know that you can check the delete button in case you pressed the add row button by accident but the problem is when there is a user that can create the entity Answer but not delete it.

Thanks in advance